# Can I use same project runner registration token to register multiple gitlab runners?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

**Title: GitLab Runner Project and Runner Registration with Tokens**

**Question:**
I'm working on setting up GitLab Runners on multiple EC2 instances and I'm confused about how to map runners to projects and manage registration tokens. Here's my scenario:

- I have several GitLab projects (p1, p2, p3, and so on).
- I want to use the same group of runners (r1, r2, r3) for multiple projects.
- Each EC2 instance is running a GitLab Runner.

I understand for each project I can generate gitlab runner registration token which when I run on any single ec2 it gets registered as runner.

The issue I'm facing is that when I run the registration command on different EC2 instances with the same token, only one runner shows up in GitLab.

Does one token can be used for only 1 runner/ec2 ? Do I need to generate separate tokens for each runner ?

I would like to understand the correct way to set up registration tokens, so I can have the same runners associated with multiple projects. How should I structure my registration tokens and runner setup to achieve this?

Any guidance or best practices for managing GitLab Runner registration and mapping to projects in this scenario would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your help!

The issue I'm facing is that when I run the registration command on different EC2 instances with the same token, only one runner shows up in GitLab project.

Answer (score 0):

You can register runners to *groups* instead of projects. Then all projects in that group can access the runner. That's probably the most straightforward approach.

You also have the ability to configure multiple runners in the `config.toml` and you can use different tokens/projects (or any runner configuration for that matter) for each runner. When you start using `gitlab-runner start` all the configured runners will run together.

Comment: This means -
1. a single project token cannot be used for multiple runners on ec2. we have to create separate project tokens for each ec2/runner ?
2. With config.toml we can register a single runner with multiple projects using different project tokens.
3. For registering runner in a group with multiple projects , If I have to register 3 runner in a group I need to create 3 registration tokens ? 

kindly correct me if I got it wrong

Comment: I want to understand does a single project token can register a single runner only ?
suppose I have 3 ec2 machines which I want to use as gitlab runner. I want to register  all of them automatically to the project.
Do I need to create separate token for each ec2 ? or can I use the same registration token

Comment: @Goural the same _registration_ token can be used. Every time you call `gitlab-runner register` a new _runner token_ is created. Though, this is changing in GitLab 17, which will use [authentication tokens](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/#register-with-a-runner-authentication-token) by default and registration tokens will be removed in GitLab 18.